# How to reset configurable to a property

Tags: javascript

I have a question about 'configurable'

If I type

```
var o = {x:1}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'x')
```

> { value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }

```
Object.defineProperty(o, 'x', {configurable: false});
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'x')
```

> { value: 1,   writable: true,   enumerable: true,   configurable:
>   false }

I studied from JavaScript - The Definitive Guide, Chapter 6-7
It says:

### If a property is not configurable, you cannot change its configurable or enumerable attributes.

I wondering is there any method to reset `configurable` to true? Or It's just a boring question?(It won't happen in any situation)

Comment: in your example configurable is set to true by default. u don't need to change.

Comment: Redefining `o = Object.assign({}, o)` works, but seems a bit hackish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set configurable to true when it is false.

```js
var o = {x:1};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'x', {
  configurable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(o, 'x', {
  configurable: true
}); // throws a TypeError
```

You just only can create a new object to replace the non-configurable object.Let the non-configurable object be removed from memory by Garbage collection.

In some case,you could set object become not-configurable to make sure other can't change obejct.

For example,if you find the perfomance problem that the Vue.js take a long time to run proxySetter.It may be a complex object attach to Vue instance,you can set complex object not configurable to avoid be observed by Vue.js.Of course,the better way is don't attach a complex object to Vue instance.

- [Ability to disable Vue observation (Github Issues)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2637)